# App preview - iPhone 6.5" Display - your app preview contains unsupported or corrupted audio

Tags: ios, iphone

We are trying to upload the app preview video by taking a video through the Quick Time player by running it on the Xcode simulator (13.2) with different devices of the iPhone. But, it's not accepting the size and is getting an error saying "your app preview contains unsupported or corrupted audio."

We tried different methods to upload this video and proceeded to submit it with an app preview. But nothing works out.

Need quick help to resolve this issue, please. Do we also need to upload videos for the 6.5 and 5.5-inch displays, as well as the iPad Pro 3rd and 2nd generations?

866 X 1920 - which iPhone to use in the simulator 13.2? Likewise for other app preview requirements of 5.5, iPad?

Thanks

**STEPS TO REPRODUCE**

I built the package using Xcode and ran it using the simulator.

I tried to record the video from the simulator's "Record video" option and "Quick Time Player". Both didn't work.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I did get it to work when I screen recorded from an actual device instead of the simulator.

Answer (score 5):

For AppStore app preview videos, you need to either add sound track or silence the video totally. You can silence video with terminal using ffmpeng. This is the command:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -i yourVideoFile.mp4  -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest yourSilentVideoFileOutput.mov
```

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to follow up on @Elmar's post. The ffmpeg command works great. For those who don't use ffmpeg, you can install it with HomeBrew using
`brew install ffmpeg`

Answer (score 0):

In final cut pro this worked for me:

For 6.5:

1. Create a custom project with dimensions 886 x 1920
2. Insert your video
3. Add a sound track
4. Combine the sound track and video as a combined clip. This was key. I didn't work just exporting with the track sound separate.
5. Export as 1080 to a m4v file.